# django.urls.reverse doesn't work as expected

Tags: django, reverse, django-urls

I set urls at project level:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', homepage_view, name='index'),
]

urlpatterns += [
    ...
    url(r'^system_notifications/$', SystemNotificationsView.as_view(), name='system_notifications'),
    url(r'^script_runner/$', ScriptRunnerView.as_view(), name='script_runner'),
]
...
```

And there is no urls set at app level.
SystemNotificationsView and ScriptRunnerView are placed in the same app.

View:

```
class ScriptRunnerView(View):
    def get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
        return {}
```

When I try in test do this:

```
reverse('script_runner')
```

I got:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'script_runner' not found. 'script_runner' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

but

```
reverse('system_notifications')
```

works well.

How to set urls for script_runner correctly?

Comment: This is too obscure. Please provide a minimal repro or show more consistent code snippets and project folder structure with all the urls.py files.